# Accelerate and clean up WordPress

Tags: cache, customization

I almost finished my WordPress site after 2 monaths... Because there were a lot of custom code work, it took me so long. Furthermore I created over 18000 sites, deleted them and was testing.

My question now is, how can I clean up and accelerate my WordPress. I think there is a lot of cache and temp files now who can be deleted.

I already have WP Super Cache, but I mean there must be something more!

Greetings and Thank You

Answer (score -1):

You can host your WordPress on a server with PHP 7 running on SSD. It speeds up by alot.